# Dart / flutter: how to build a form with multiple user input fields easily

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to build a form where I have multiple `TextField` widgets, and want to have a button that composes and e-mail when pressed, by passing the data gathered from these fields.

For this, I started building an `InheritedWidget` to contain `TextField`-s, and based on the action passed in the constructor - functionality not yet included in the code below - it would return a different text from via `toString` method override.

As I understood, an `InheritedWidget` holds it's value as long as it is part of the current Widget tree (so, for example, if I navigate from the form it gets destroyed and the value is lost).

Here is how I built my TextForm using InheritedWidget:

```
class TextInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  const TextInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final String text;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TextInheritedWidget old) {
    return text != old.text;
  }

  static TextInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(TextInheritedWidget);
  }

}

class TextInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new TextInputWidgetState();
}

class TextInputWidgetState extends State<TextInputWidget> {
  String text;
  TextEditingController textInputController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TextInheritedWidget(
      text: text,
      child: new TextField(
        controller: textInputController,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: adoptionHintText
        ),
        onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
            this.text = textInputController.text;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString({DiagnosticLevel minLevel: DiagnosticLevel.debug}) {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return 'Név: ' + text;
  }
}
```

And here is the button that launches the e-mail sending:

```
TextInputWidget nameInputWidget = new TextInputWidget();
  TextInheritedWidget inherited = new TextInheritedWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Örökbefogadás'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Név:', style: infoText16BlackBold,),
            nameInputWidget,
            new FlatButton(onPressed: () {
              launchAdoptionEmail(nameInputWidget.toString(), 'kutya');
            },
                child: new Text('Jelentkezem'))

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

My problem is that the `nameInputWidget.toString()` simply returns TextInputWidget (class name) and I can't seem to find a way to access the `TextInputWidgetState.toString()` method.

I know that `TextInheritedWidget` holds the `text` value properly, but I'm not sure how I could access that via my `nameInputWidget` object.

Shouldn't the `TextInputWidget` be able to access the data via the context the `InheritedWidget` uses to determine which `Widget` to update and store the value of?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. **Only children of an InheritedWidget can access it's properties**

The solution would be to have your `InheritedWidget` somewhere *above* your `Button`. But that imply you'd have to refactor to take this into account.

Answer (score 2):

Following Rémi's remarks, I came up with a working solution, albeit I'm pretty sure it is not the best and not to be followed on a massive scale, but should work fine for a couple of fields.

The solution comes by handling all `TextField` widgets inside one single `State`, alongside the e-mail composition.

In order to achieve a relatively clean code, we can use a custom function that build an input field with the appropriate data label, which accepts two input parameters: a `String` and a `TextEditingController`.

The `label` is also used to determine which variable the `setState()` method will pass the newly submitted text.

```
Widget buildTextInputRow(var label, TextEditingController textEditingController) {
    return new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, top: 2.0, right: 5.0  ),
                  child: new Text(label, style: infoText16BlackBold)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
                  child: new TextField(
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: adoptionHintText),
                      onChanged: (String str) {
                        setState(() {
                          switch(label) {
                            case 'Név':
                              tempName = 'Név: ' + textEditingController.text + '\r\n';
                              break;
                            case 'Kor':
                              tempAge = 'Kor: ' + textEditingController.text + '\r\n';
                              break;
                            case 'Cím':
                              tempAddress = 'Cím: ' + textEditingController.text + '\r\n';
                              break;
                            default:
                              break;
                          }
                        });
                      }
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

The problem is obviously that you will need a new TextEditingController and a new String to store every new input you want the user to enter:

```
  TextEditingController nameInputController = new TextEditingController();
  var tempName;
  TextEditingController ageInputController = new TextEditingController();
  var tempAge;
  TextEditingController addressInputController = new TextEditingController();
  var tempAddress;
```

This will result in a lot of extra lines if you have a lot of fields, and you will also have to update the `composeEmail()` method accordingly, and the more fields you have, you will be more likely to forget a couple.

```
  var emailBody;
  composeEmail(){
    emailBody = tempName + tempAge + tempAddress;
    return emailBody;
  }
```

Finally, it is time to build the form:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Örökbefogadás'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildTextInputRow('Név', nameInputController),
          buildTextInputRow('Kor', ageInputController),
          buildTextInputRow('Cím', addressInputController),
          new FlatButton(onPressed: () { print(composeEmail()); }, child: new Text('test'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

*For convenience, I just printed the e-mail body to the console while testing*

```
I/flutter ( 9637): Név: Zoli
I/flutter ( 9637): Kor: 28
I/flutter ( 9637): Cím: Budapest
```

All this is handled in a single `State`.